# "So that" and "Such was"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-order

> 36. Mary was **so disappointed that** she could not keep working.

→ Such was________________________________

> 38. The children were **so excited that** they talked about the show all night long.

→ Such was_______________________________

Ex 1: It rained so heavily that he couldn't go to the party.
→ So heavily did it rain that he couldn't go to the party.

Ex2: The actor is so popular that everyone recognizes him wherever he comes.
→ So popular is the actor that everyone recognizes him wherever he comes.

English is my second language, Vietnamese is my mother tongue

Comment: I'm sorry but it's unclear what your question is. Could you please explain more completely?

Comment: Welcome to ELL Linh. I don't understand the "such was" in your question. What are you asking for help with? Are you trying to transform the sentences to use "such was"? Please [edit] your question to add more explanation. Don't worry if your writing isn't perfect - we will help.

Comment: I think it should be something like this: *Such was Mary's disappointment that she could not keep working.*, etc. The difference is explained at [the Cambridge Dictionary website](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/such-or-so), and the table there sums it up quite well (*so* + adjective; *such* + noun phrase).

Comment: ...also, *so* + adverb, as in your examples.

Answer (score 1):

*Such* here can also mean ***so great***.

And we have the structure: **So + adjective + be + noun + that clause**

So we have an answer to your transformation questions.

36. Such (= So great) was **Mary's disappointment that she could not keep working.**
37. Such (= So great) was **the children's excitement that they talked about the show all night long.**